# Angular js radio button is not running in

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular js.Creating a stuff using angular js.Using radio button to select item .But this not running in my sysytem. http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/559/.       copyied code form jsfiddle.
It contain the file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/
     1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Got output

```
{{ showStatus() }}
```

Any body say the reason of not running the code  in my system?

Comment: Are you using the same angular version as the example from fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

`editable-radiolist` and `e-ng-options` are not standard angular directives.
Click on 'External Resources' on the left - u'll see that this example also uses:

```
xeditable.js 
bootstrap.min.css 
xeditable.css 
checklist-model.js
```